# Installing Apple Watch App From Testflight Internal Testing Error: Application Verification Failed

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, testflight

I have successfully installed and tested the Watch app locally on my Watch from Xcode many times and everything installed and worked perfectly.  Once I uploaded the build to iTunes Connect and installed it from testflight the iphone app installs fine but the watch app errors out at about 80% with the following error: `Failed to install [app name], error: Application Verification Failed`.

Some info about the project:

I am using App Groups and the entitlements are all correct as far as that goes.  I've also checked to make sure that the iOS Deployment Target listed in my WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension targets are both set to 8.2.

My main app target deployment target is set to 8.0.

My watchkit app includes a pod install of MagicalRecord 2.2.0

Comment: Have you gone into TestFlight and tried to install it from there by flippint the little switch?

Comment: Did not even see that toggle.  AND that fixed the problem thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that works for you!

Comment: Can someone post a screenshot of the switch? All I see is:Offers Apple Watch App

Comment: @DovD. Do you have an apple watch paired with the device? You should see the switch.  http://cl.ly/bBh8

Comment: @TravisBeck Yes, I do have a watch paired with the device. Instead of the switch in the image you sent, it just says "Offers Apple Watch App"

Comment: @DovD. that's weird.  Do you have a screenshot?  If you didnt' have an apple watch paired it would have a label instead of a switch that says "Apple watch not paired" But it's not even giving you the option

Comment: @DovD. I am experiencing the same issue. I'm currently trying this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881528/cant-install-watchkit-app-on-apple-watch.

Comment: @TravisBeck For me, this was related to another bug in TestFlight, see stackoverflow.com/a/30584082/2615958. I guess TestFlight thought that the app never finished installing because the CFBundleVersion didn't match, and when I quit TestFlight and launched it again, it thought there was a newer version available. So, the switch never showed up.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [rmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244169/installing-apple-watch-app-from-testflight-internal-testing-error-application-v?noredirect=1#comment48597275_30244169) Once I installed the watch app by flipping the switch from within the testflight app, it installed with no problems.

Comment: I figured this out the first time, forgot, and had to re-discover it here the second time. Sheesh! But thanks stackoverflow. (I know "thank-yous" are discouraged...