# This Code Signature is no longer supported when building app on iPhone 12

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The solution on the other post with a similar title: [The code signature version is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported) DOES NOT WORK.

I used to be able to install my app onto my phone. I have updated my phone and then I updated xCode so that I could install it to IOS 14.6, and now I get this code signature version is no longer supported error. It runs fine on the simulator but not on my phone.

I get this error output:

````
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
"com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
0  DTDeviceKitBase  0x000000011cf093b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
1  DTDeviceKitBase  0x000000011cf47ae1 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
2  DVTFoundation  0x000000010d602bac DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
3  DTDeviceKitBase  0x000000011cf47822 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
4  IDEiOSSupportCore  0x0000000122c3c999 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.294 + 3534
5  DVTFoundation  0x000000010d735921 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
6  DVTFoundation  0x000000010d73754b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
7  libdispatch.dylib  0x00007fff2019a5dd _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8  libdispatch.dylib  0x00007fff2019b7c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9  libdispatch.dylib  0x00007fff201a15fe _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
10 libdispatch.dylib  0x00007fff201a20cb _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
11 libdispatch.dylib  0x00007fff201abc5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff20343499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff20342467 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
System Information
macOS Version 11.0.1 (Build 20B29)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-08-25T17:09:00-07:00 ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The code signature version is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported)

Answer (score 33):

In Xcode, Add the `--generate-entitlement-der` to your `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS` under Build Settings in your target.

If it still doesn't work.

Go to Targets => General => Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content

1. Find the frameworks that are set to 'Embed & Sign'
2. Show in Finder of this Framework / xcFramework (both Framework / xcFramework can have static and dynamic frameworks so we need to find which is static one)
3. In Terminal run `file ***.framework`
   (If you are using xcFramework check the file with framework extension. Example path would like as `Test.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/Test.framework`)
4. If it says `Shared Library / Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64`. Don't do anything to the setting.
5. If it says current ar archive，then it is a static library, just need to change it from `Embed & Sign` to `Do Not Embed`.
6. Repeat for all embedded frameworks

It should work fine

Comment: Thank you! Finally it works

Comment: The framework part was the solution! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it works like a formula! For people who are using Flutter module, `FlutterPluginRegistrant.xcframework` is probably static.