# iOS 15 - Enterprise provisioning profile (inHouse) - The code signature is no longer supported - iOS App with watch extension - DER entitlement issue

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos, ios15

We are using an Enterprise provisioning profile for our apps. With the iOS 15, we started getting the issue "The code signature version is no longer supported".

For mobile-only app, we solved this by adding a flag to Xcode -> Target -> Build settings

```
OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS: --generate-entitlement-der
```

But the app with the watchOS extension is still not working and gives the same error "The code signature version is no longer supported.". We checked mobile has -6, -7 signatures but the watch extension inside the mobile app does not have -6, -7 signatures.

We have applied --generate-entitlement-der to all the targets but it is still not working.

Environment: Xcode 12.5.1, MAC OS - Big Sur 11.5.2

Any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The problem was fixed by setting all the static frameworks from 'Sign and Embed' to 'Do Not Embed'. This was done for every target

I answered in detail over here

[This Code Signature is no longer supported when building app on iPhone 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931476/this-code-signature-is-no-longer-supported-when-building-app-on-iphone-12/69381225#69381225)

Note: Also, you need to use Xcode 13.1 otherwise watch app won't install