# Can't Install SwiftUI app onto my iPhone 13 Pro when I add Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

My test App runs on the 13 Pro simulator with XCode 13, but when I try to build it to my physical iPhone device, it gives me the "unable to install" error. Under details of the failed install I recieve:

**Details**

```
Unable to install "SwiftUI_FireBaseChatApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-06-15 19:33:21 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110ea1614 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110edadd8 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106071be8 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110edab30 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1336
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e039590 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 2916
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106198f68 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010619a080 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 364
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b08ae5f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b08b01b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b08b78a8 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b08b8404 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b08c2c98 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b0a70360 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b0a6f080 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.5 (19F77)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 5015;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 13.4 (20503) (Build 13F17a)
Timestamp: 2022-06-16T01:03:21+05:30
```

I looked at a few other posts with the same "code signature version is no longer supported" error to see if those would work, but so far none have. Here's one of the solutions proposed: [Codesign Signature Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported)

The code builds and runs perfectly on the simulator. Just won't install to my iPhone 13 Pro for testing. I've yet to implement any Firebase Authentication in the app (I'm just exploring firebase for the first time). Also, If I recall, my firestore database is in production mode, not test mode, so is it some security rule issue? I'm confused.

My test app is very bare bone. I've simply created a custom object in swift and tried inserting it into the database:

**ContentView.swift** (The snippet of code I've added to the boiler plate code):

```
public struct City: Codable {

    let name: String
    let state: String?
    let country: String?
    let isCapital: Bool?
    let population: Int64?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case state
        case country
        case isCapital = "capital"
        case population
    }

    func addItem() {

        let db = Firestore.firestore() // get a firestore manager object.

        let city = City(name: "Los Angeles",
                        state: "CA",
                        country: "USA",
                        isCapital: false,
                        population: 5000000)

        do {
            try db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(from: city)
        } catch _ {
            // handle errors.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you selected "automatic signing" under signing & capabilities for your project in Xcode?

Comment: Try running it on your phone, then once it fails, go to Settings -> General -> VPN & Device Management and, if the issue is about trust certificates, then just hit "Trust this developer".

Comment: Delete the app from the iPhone : it may happens that with new xCode version , it can not update version created with previous one. Add this problem with last xCode. (Not beta)

Comment: @Paulw11 Yup. It's enabled.

Comment: @Stoic Have that enabled as well on my iPhone. Other apps without Firebase packages install without any hiccups on my phone. It's specifically the dependencies that are causing this issue.

Comment: @PtitXav A previous version of the app doesn't exist. Since I created this project solely for firebase testing, I hadn't installed it on my device before adding the packages to my project.

Comment: How did you add Firebase; SPM or Cocoapods? Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931476/this-code-signature-is-no-longer-supported-when-building-app-on-iphone-12) is almost exactly the same as yours. Did you try that solution?

Comment: @Jay I've tried the generate-der part, but not the others. Let me try the rest and report back if it works now.