# Getting Signature Error in Xcode, because of package dependency?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

So I have a Project that has Firebase package dependencies in Xcode. Whenever I try to run it on my real iPhone (not the simulator, my actual iPhone) I get the error as follows [enter image description here][image: 1] Now I started a fresh new Hello World project and it runs fine on my iPhone. However, the moment I add firebase package dependency to the Hello World Project I got the same error I was getting with my original project.

So does anyone know if package dependencies can cause signature issues? Any input shall be appreciated!

PS: Details of the error:[enter image description here][image: 2]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? What version of the firebase modules are you using? How are you installing firebase? Pods? Swift package manager?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931476/this-code-signature-is-no-longer-supported-when-building-app-on-iphone-12

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.